# DFA delete not acceptable characters

Tags: list, prolog, dfa

So i represent this DFA:

[image]

Like this

```
initial(0).
final(2).
arc(0,a,1).
arc(0,b,0).
arc(1,a,1).
arc(1,b,2).
arc(2,a,2).
arc(2,b,2).
```

And i have a predicate that parse a string and returns true if is acceptable:

```
transition(X,[A|B]) :- arc(X,A,T),transition(T,B).  
transition(X,[]) :- final(X).
parse(X) :- initial(S),transition(S,X).
```

Now i want to make a predicate `check(X,Y)` thats take a list and delete all the indexes that is not `a` or `b`. Y will be a new list that doest contain the wrong indexes.

eg:

```
?-check([a,1,b,c,b],Y).
Y=[a,b,b];
false
```

I am not into Prolog  and i tried a lot of stuff, but nothing did what i need.
Can you give me a guideline how to make the check predicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a list of char-atoms, such as `[a,b,c,d,e,f,a,b,c]` and you want it to be `[a,b,a,b]`. The empty list is your base case:

```
check([], []).
```

Then, worry about if the current char is in your acceptable list:

```
check([C|Cs], Result) :- 
    check(Cs, Rs),
    (arc(_, C, _) 
        -> Result = [C|Rs]
        ;  Result = Rs).
```

In action:

```
?- check([a,b,c,d,a,b,e], X).
X = [a, b, a, b].
```

You can use `string_chars/2` to convert between SWI strings and this representation if necessary:

```
?- string_chars("abcdabe", S), check(S, SFiltered), string_chars(FilteredString, SFiltered).
S = [a, b, c, d, a, b, e],
SFiltered = [a, b, a, b],
FilteredString = "abab".
```